# Alternative to Loop with very large dictionary in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary

I have a dictionary with around half a million key/item pairs that i need to dump to a excel sheet. I can't use Application.Transpose(Dict.Keys) and Application.Transpose(Dict.Items) because there seems to be a limit of 65536 (2^16).

As an alternative I've considered looping over the dict and write the key and item to the cells. This takes several hours and seems very inefficient.

Any suggestions how I can do better?

Comment: first write them to a variant array, then you can assign the whole array in bulk to the sheet.

Comment: But how do I write the arrays to the sheet? I need to write each array vertical, which i would do with transpose but again the array is to big for transpose.

Comment: See Tim's answer below.  You create a 2D array and then just assign it, no need for Transpose.

Answer (score 4):

As Scott says:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    Dim i As Long, arr, t, k
    Dim dict As Object
    
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    t = Timer
    For i = 1 To 500000
        dict.Add CStr("Key" & Format(i, "000000")), True
    Next i
    Debug.Print "Loaded dictionary", Timer - t
    
    ReDim arr(1 To dict.Count, 1 To 2)
    i = 0
    For Each k In dict
        i = i + 1
        arr(i, 1) = k
        arr(i, 2) = dict(k)
    Next k
    
    Debug.Print "Loaded array", Timer - t
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Resize(dict.Count, 2).Value = arr
    Debug.Print "Put array on sheet", Timer - t
End Sub
```

Output (times in seconds):

```txt
Loaded dictionary      13.9 
Loaded array           27.3 
Put array on sheet     28.8
```

Comment: Curious if going early-bound with the dictionary could make a visible difference, given there's a million iterations over it.

Comment: Looks like a very slight (<10%) improvement.  500k is getting to the large end of what the dictionary object can efficiently manage I think: loading 100k keys takes 0.6sec but 500k takes 15 sec not 3 sec...